# Get first day of the month

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to get an NSDate object from the first day of the current month. I use the following code:

```
    NSDateComponents *components = [c components:(NSEraCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    components.day = 1;

    NSDate *dayOneInCurrentMonth = [c dateFromComponents:components];
```

However when I log this date, it gives me the day before

```
day one = 2013-09-30 22:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: Is your time zone UTC -2? In this case, dayOneInCurrentMonth is the correct date, but NSLog outputs it with this time zone correction

Comment: @Jeepston You and Joel were right. It's the timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are logging the date in GMT time zone (+0000). Try logging this:

NSLog(@"new date: %@", [dayOneInCurrentMonth descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]]);